# Spring Boot/Spring Cloud - Eureka server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying out the eureka cloud registry for the first time and looking for your help on it

To register sample Eureka client to the eureka server
The code for Eureka Server is in the following location
https://github.com/vijayakumar-psg587/EurekaServer.git

This is the Client I am trying to register
https://github.com/vijayakumar-psg587/EurekaClient1.git

But the client is not getting registered

```
Request execution failure with status code 404; retrying on another server if available
2017-09-17 00:11:04.433 ERROR 17432 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_EUREKACLIENT1/EurekaClient1 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1030) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:944) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:444) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:304) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:51) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:192) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed07235b.CGLIB$eurekaClient$1(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
```

I use Spring Boot - 1.4.6 version.

I have a similar eureka server which runs on the port 8880 and if I try to register my client there it works perfectly. not sure what I am missing in the new server I've written

Is there something to do with the server port series ? The working one has the port configured as 8880 whereas the one I am having trouble is configured as 9000 . Please let me know your thoughts

Working EurekaServer- https://github.com/vijayakumar-psg587/CloudConfigEurekaServer.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EurekaClient1/bootstrap.yml, use:

```
defaultZone: http://localhost:9000/eureka/
```

instead of:

```
defaultZone: http://localhost:9000/eurekaServer/
```